# Create desktop entry for executable

Tags: .desktop, executable

I'm sure the solution for this is trivial, but I haven't found the way to create a desktop file for an executable!

My desktop file is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MOHAA LINUX
Exec=mohaa_lnx
Type=Application
Categories=Game;
StartupNotify=true
Path="/home/lucho/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/EA GAMES/MOHAA/"
Icon=BE1A_MOHAA.0
Terminal=false
```

How I currently run this application is on a terminal window, cd-ing into the Path above, and then running `./mohaa_lnx`. I have tried many options in the Exec bit, like `./mohaa_lnx`, `sh mohaa_lnx`... but I get the same type of error:

```
Failed to execute child process "mohaa_lnx" (No such file or directory)
```

Googling the above message hasn't been useful.

More info about folders and file:

```
lucho@lucho-HP:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/EA GAMES/MOHAA$ ls -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lucho lucho 2027088 Sep  3  2004 mohaa_lnx
```

Answer (score 2):

From my experience with `.desktop` files, you need to actually put the whole path in for the executable; I'm not exactly sure what the `path` field is for.

Change what comes after `Exec:` to `/home/lucho/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/EA\ GAMES/MOHAA/mohaa_lnx`

Also, change the `Path:` field to reflect that with the backslashes. You can't use quotes for spaces and special characters in Linux, as far as I have seen.

For future reference, put a backslash (`\`) before *any* special character, including spaces. Windows uses quotes.

The complete file should look something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MOHAA for LINUX
Exec=/home/lucho/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/EA\ GAMES/MOHAA/mohaa_lnx
Type=Application
Categories=Game;
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/lucho/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/EA\ GAMES/MOHAA/
Icon=BE1A_MOHAA.0
Terminal=false
```

Comment: It doesn't work... any combination, without using `Path`, with `Path`, without quotes, with quotes...  Can you give full code please? Updated post with my username and more info about folder and file.

Comment: I'll edit it in. Same error?

Comment: Yes: `Failed to execute command "/home/lucho/.wine/drive_c/Program Files \(x86\)/EA GAME/MOHAA/mohaa_lnx". Failed to execute child process "/home/lucho/.wine/drive_c/Program" (No such file or directory)`

Comment: There needs to be a backslash after the word "program" and after the word "files." You're missing those two

Comment: The error comes after running the code in your post. That is not the problem. It's so weird. I though it would be easy!

Comment: Your error looks different than what I posted so I don't know either. Try making a shortcut with no space in the name to the Program Files folder and point through that instead.